# Rails 3. Checking for true values in SQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I need to check if the column `exam` has a value of `true`. So I set this up but it doesn't work...

```
@exam_shipments = Shipment.where("exam <> NULL AND exam <> 0 AND customer_id = ?", current_admin_user.customer_id)

# This one gives me error "SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: true:"
@exam_shipments = Shipment.where("exam = true AND customer_id = ?", current_admin_user.customer_id) 

@exam_shipments = Shipment.where("exam = 1 AND customer_id = ?", current_admin_user.customer_id)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really just stick to AR syntax:

```
@exam_shipments = Shipment.where(:exam => true, :customer_id => current_admin_user.customer_id)
```

Assuming `:exam` is a boolean field on your `Shipment` model.  ActiveRecord takes care of converting your query to the proper syntax for the given database.  So the less inline SQL you write, the more database-agnostic and portable your code will be.

Comment: Maybe for the actual cause of this: several database types do not provide an actual Boolean datatype. ActiveRecord emulates those by various means: a single character being either `t` or `f` for SQLite, a TINYINT being either `0` or `1` for MySQL or well, a boolean field for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need do execute SQL?

It's much easier just to do

```
@exam_shipments = Shipment.find_by_id(current_admin_user.customer_id).exam?
```